# My Storyboard suddenly stock as wChR, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio 2017 (15.5). Suddenly, my StoryBoard show my views as wChR, and I couldn't let it back to the previous (normal) view. a screenshot is attached.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k200I.png)

Comment: Update Xcode and VS to the latest.  Try to open it from Xcode .

Comment: Same issue, update both visual studio on Windows, visual studio on Mac, and Xcode. Same issue !